# Where should I persist the side effects of actions?

Tags: redux, dataflow

I have a outlining app that I am writing using **unidirectional dataflow** and some of the concepts from **Redux**.

When the user has selects items in the outline, and clicks indent, an **indent action** is fired.  This needs to update the **state** of the app via some complex rules that modify the `parent` property of some, if not all, of the items being indented.

These changes also need to persist out to a **web service**.

I do not want to repeat this logic in multiple places.

The question is, should I be applying this logic inside of the **middleware**, and just passing along simpler **actions** to the **reducer**? Or should I be somehow analyzing the **state** after the **reducer** has applied the logic and then sending the changes to the **web service**?

Comment: Is this a web app, mobile app or desktop application? An embedded system?

Comment: And what do you mean by "middleware"?

Comment: This is a web app (specifically a PWA).  If you are familiar with Redux, middleware is code that lies between an action an a reducer.